# Applying PC rotation obtained from centered data to un-centered data

Tags: pca, centering

Let $X$ be an $n\times p$ matrix. We obtain a matrix $Z$ by removing the mean from each column of $X$.

Let $Z=UDV^T$. Principal components are $Z \cdot V$. What is the interpretation of $X \cdot V$?

Comment: If this is homework or self-study please add the [tag:self-study] and tell us what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/73380/3277